# Convertir Array String en Array float

Tags: ios, array, xcode, string, objective-c

Gente tengo todo un reto tengo que convertir arrayString en arrayFloat 
no es como normalmente se hace

```
 array *date = [obj valueForKey:@"oficialTime"];// por ejemplo 10:10:02
 float f = [date floatValue];
```

El problema aqui e que array esta en formato Nsdate hh:mm:ss

```
 array *date = [obj valueForKey:@"oficialTime"];
 { 02:03:03  01:02:03  10:10:02 }
```

Cuando hago la conversión float me entrega estos valores

```
20000,10000,10000
```

Me las he arreglado y logrado que float me entrege los valores completo pero sin separación de los puntos

Ahora tengo estos datos

```
20303,10203,101002,
```

El problema es que esto suige siendo un string y necesito estos valores en float pero con la separación de los puntos por que debo determinar las horas minutos y segundos pero float no reconoce los dos puntos(:) 
y por supuesto en Array

un array float serai algo como esto

```
NSAarrayFloat= @[@2, @3, @4,@5];//float
```

cuando yo lo que necesito es algo como esto

```
NSAarrayFloat= @[@02:03:03, @01:02:03, @01:02:03];//float
```

Comment: En este ejemplo, los valores de `NSAarrayFloat= @[@02:03:03, @01:02:03, @01:02:03];` no son de tipo `float`... ¿Qué es lo que vas a hacer luego con estos valores?

Comment: Estas seguro que quieres un float, o quizás quieres una marca temporal? Además sería amable de considerar un mínimo de puntuación, no solamente los compiladores entienden mejor con ella.

Comment: Ya lo se que no son float me las arregle para convertirlo en un valor completo por ejemplo 20303 en vez de 2:03:03   esto me sirve el pero esto sigue siendo un string solo necesito estos valores en un array float los valores después son representado en un grafico  como este https://github.com/Jawbone/JBChartView

Comment: Basicamnete necesiratia un Array float como este

Comment: NSArrayFloat= @[@20303, @010203, @010203];

Answer (score 1):

Haz un bucle que pase por ese array tuyo de string y conviertelos uno a uno a float asi:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;


float value = [numberFormatter numberFromString:@"32.12"].floatValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo trabajar con un arreglo de arreglos. Pienso que no debes trabajar con floats, ya que las horas no tiene flotantes porque siempre tienen este formato: "int:int:int"

```
NSArray<NSString*>* arrayStrings = @[@"02:03:03", @"01:02:03", @"10:10:02"];
NSMutableArray< NSArray<NSNumber*>* > *arrayInts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:arrayStrings.count];
for (NSString *s in arrayStrings) {
    NSArray *timeComponentsString = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@":"]; //esto produce un arreglo de strings [@"02", @"03", @"03"]
    NSArray *timeComponentsInt = @[ @([timeComponentsString[0] intValue]), @([timeComponentsString[1] intValue]), @([timeComponentsString[2] intValue]) ]; //esto produce un arreglo de ints [@02, @03, @03]
    [arrayInts addObject: timeComponentsInt];
}
```

El arreglo arrayInts será un arreglo de arreglo de enteros, siguiendo el ejemplo tendría estos valores:

```
[
[@02, @03, @03],
[@01, @02, @03],
[@10, @10, @02]
]
```